# jQuery how to select an element from a element

Tags: jquery

I want to select a table row from a special table.

**HTML**:

```
<table id="player_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="123"> ... </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I select it? Maybe like this?

**jQuery**:

```
$("#player_table > tbody tr."+idOfPlayerRpwWhoWasClickedAtPlayersTable)
```

Comment: `.` selects a class, `#` selects an ID. `tr.` should be `tr#` but why not just `$("#"+idOfPlayerRpwWhoWasClickedAtPlayersTable)` ? IDs must be unique and preferrably not begin with a digit

Comment: @mplungjan: thanks for your help! THe problem is, I have this ID 2 times one time at my players Table and one time at the playerField section... i know this is not valid and not good! but how this 2 IDs has to give sometimes some data to each other...

Comment: Having repeated `id` is invalid HTML and a problem which you should really fix.

Comment: $("#player_table").find("#"+idOfPlayerRpwWhoWasClickedAtPlayersTable) you may use like it.

Answer (score 0):

Id attribute must be unique for the elements in the page.

So you can reach the element like;

```
$('#'+idOfPlayerRpwWhoWasClickedAtPlayersTable);
```

Comment: i know but at the moment sometbody gave me the page and i have to fix these issues... and exactly in this moment its not possible to change the code to get only one time the ID unique...

Comment: So you have to start fixing the multiple ids